# Problema na renderização da imagem

Tags: html, css

A imagem tá toda "pixelada" não fica como deveria, o que pode ser?

A imagem original tem ótima resolução e o tamanho dela tá 1200x1200, diminuir o tamanho dela também não mudou o resultado

No CSS estou usando

```
width: 40px; height: 40px;
```

E no HTML

```
<img src="images/image.png">
```

A imagem fica assim nos navegadores

[image]

Comment: Está dando esse problemas em todos os Browsers? Já considerou transformar o .png em .svg?

Comment: Não era pra acontecer isso não. Talvez seja o formato ou a codificação da imagem. Se puder disponibilizar a imagem original para download para ser analisada seria bom.

Answer (score 1):

Ao comprimir a imagem, ela irá perder qualidade, mesmo que seja boa, isso acontece em todos os formatos que usam pixels, exemplo `bmp`, `jpeg`, `png`...

Pois esse tipo de construção só trabalha bem em determinadas distancias e tamanhos, dependendo da compressão, o browser não irá conseguir calcular as curvas e os pixels irão ficar expostos, exemplo...

[image: Imagem em pixels]

A solução perfeita é usar vetores, pois eles são interpretados pelos browsers como elementos visuais matemáticos, então sempre irão se manter intactos nas bordas.

É possível criar vetores a partir de programas avançados como CoreDraw e Illustrator, mas o que uso e recomendo é a criação/edição de vetores com [Vectr](https://vectr.com/), pois além de ser grátis e online é fácil de usar...

Comment: Passei pra svg, e resolveu no chrome mas no IE tá o mesmo problema

Comment: Como assim o mesmo problema? ele exibe pixelado? já tentou setar as dimensões do svg no css/html? vale lembrar que é suportado até a versão 9 do IE https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece ao redimensionar a imagem.

Sugiro editar sua imagem e salvar já na resolução que irá usá-la.

Se de todo modo ainda não ficar da forma ideal, o melhor a se fazer é desenhá-la novamente já nesse tamanho que irá utilizar, assim não perderá nenhuma informação.

Answer (score 0):

Imagens circulares costumam ter esse problema quando comprimidas, Principalmente pelo fato de não existir "meio pixel". Observe as imagens abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagens em painéis de alta densidade de pixel, como o *painel Retina da Apple*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os Browser não renderizam imagens tão bem quanto o Photoshop por exemplo. Então as vezes no Photoshop fica bom, mas o algorítimo do Browser pode não ter o mesmo resultado comprimindo imagens.

Muito provavelmente se sua imagem fosse um quadrado com linhas restas você não teria esse problema de forma tão acentuada.

O ideal seria tratar a imagem em algum software feito para isso. Ou transformar em .SVG. Tratar esse tipo de coisa no browser para mim é gambiarra. Apesar disso você pode tenar usar a classe `image-rendering: crisp-edges;` na imagem.

```
img {
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

Aqui tem documentação sobre a classe: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Apesar disso veja como mesmo com ela a `image-rendering: pixelated;` renderização nos Browser é diferente.

> **Chrome:**
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Safari:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **FireFox Quantum:**
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Você também pode tratar a imagem com JavaScript dentro de um `canvas`, como nesse exemplo:

***Para testar onde estiver False coloque True no script***

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var textarea = document.getElementById('code');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
var edit = document.getElementById('edit');
var code = textarea.value;

function drawCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  eval(textarea.value);
}

reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textarea.value = code;
  drawCanvas();
});

edit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textarea.focus();
})

textarea.addEventListener('input', drawCanvas);
window.addEventListener('load', drawCanvas);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200" class="playable-canvas"></canvas>
<div class="playable-buttons">
  <input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
  <input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" />
</div>
<textarea id="code" class="playable-code" style="height:140px;">
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png';
img.onload = function() {
 ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 200);
};</textarea>
```

**Fonte:** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled